# What is best (easier / faster) approach to update private nodejs packages tree

Tags: node.js, npm, private-repository

Recently I started to use a private npm packages for backend.
They stored on our private packages server (an npm repository I deployed among application components.

And while I mostly like how it all works and happens, but there is a gotcha.
Imagine a packages like:
`@example/logging`, `@example/utilities`, `@example/validation`, `@example/database`, `@example/security` - low-level packages. And many of these low-level packages depends on `@selfcad/logging` package.
`@example/updates-queue`, `@example/subscriptions`, `@example/auth-tools`, `@example/cloud-functions` and `@example/backend-core` packages are representing high-level abstractions and components. Each of high-level packages depending on few or sometimes all of low-level packages.
Some of these packages are referenced in cloud functions via `@example/cloud-functions` package, especially low-level packages. Other used directly in a cloud functions.
Plus there is a backend component where most of packages are used directly.

So, true headache starts, when a change must be made e. g. in the low-level package like `@example/logging` or `@example/validation`.

And what is the most easier way to spread the update or fix to widely referenced lower package? With nested dependencies.
Like so: a package, e. g. `@example/validation` referenced *directly* and *indirectly*, like `@example/configuration` uses `@example/validation`, `@example/database` uses `@example/validation` and I updated `@example/validation` internals. How to spread such update across packages?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should have a look to [Yarn Workspaces](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/workspaces/). This is a useful feature of yarn to link dependent packages each others using a mono repo. This feature also includes auto-discovery/auto-linking.

Comment: I still not sure how this can help to improve the flow of upgrading dependencies in a packages tree. I thought about some tool that would help me to upgrade a packages tree in a more automatic manner. Imagine if I will switched these packages I told about to monorepo with workspaces, but I can not understand how this will help me to promote dependency upgrade across packages tree in more automated way